# assertion failed on expression succeed unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently downloaded unity onto my new computer. However, whenever I open in I only get a blank work space window with the warning of Assertion failed on SUCCEED(hr). I haven't used unity in years and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem on their forums. I have tried re-downloading [Here is a link to an screenshot I took of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wLI2.png) unity in different versions. I have also tried downloading their projects. Nothing is working, does anyone have any idea what could be going on? thank you!

Comment: Maybe It's something with your .net or mono. Try removing it all and doing  clean install

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I managed to get this fixed. It turned out to be the graphics driver my computer was running. I went in and changed the settings for unity and now the project loads just fine!

Comment: @k.bice is it possible to list the steps on how to? I can't seem to find which settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch from Nvidia GPU to integrated graphics in the NVIDIA Configuration/Settings in the Taskbar.